# Python - 'ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'

Tags: python, file, datetime

I have a .txt file and its contents is as follows:

```
---------------
0,
test1
test@gmail
19/12/2016
---------------
```

I'm attemping to read the date and compare it to the present one.

Now, it gives me the message in the title, but I've tried to format the present date and the date I read from my file to fit `%d/%m/%Y`. so I suspect it's a reading-from-file problem, but I can't find my mistake.

```
present = datetime.now()  # Get current time
print "Present time: ", present.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')  # Format present time

with open("birthday.txt", 'r') as database:
    last_line = database.readline()[-1]
    while junk != last_line:
        junk = database.readline().strip('\n')
        name_bday = database.readline().strip('\n')
        mail_bday = database.readline().strip('\n')
        date_bday = database.readline().strip('\n')

        print junk
        print name_bday
        print mail_bday
        print date_bday

        list_date = time.strptime(date_bday, "%d/%m/%Y")
        date = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(list_date))

        if date == present:
            print "It's your birthday!"
        else:
            print "It's not your birthday."
```

Comment: `database.readline()[-1]` doesn't return the last line in the file.

Comment: Oh, I thought it did. How else would you do this then?

Comment: @javanewbie `database.readlines()[-1]`. With `s` after `readline`

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri This is correct, but you can't call `readline` after calling `readlines` as it consumes the generator. Either way OP needs to use a  different logic.

Comment: @javanewbie is the text file structure constant?

Comment: You can start by `lines = database.readlines()`, then just use `lines`.

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes. That's `True`. Better way will be to remove the `while` loop and iterate using for. That way OP do not even need to make a check for last line

Comment: The structure will remain constant yes, but of course more entries will fill the file up

Comment: @Moinuddin Quadri I did that to begin with, but wasn't sure what to put as range

Comment: I think you're running into issues due to a poor initial choice of format. If you have any control of the content of the file, consider using a more structured format like CSV or JSON, or use an actual simple database like SQLite; all of these are supported by the standard library.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hah yes, but my teacher is limiting my resources however to a single .txt file.

Comment: You can store CSV or JSON in a text file just file. One line per person in a CSV format would be much easier to deal with.

Comment: Very true, but I mean she is only allowing us to use a .txt file with the format being .txt

Comment: @javanewbie nothing is stopping you from using a JSON format and saving the file as txt. Python (most of the cases) doesn't care about file extensions.

Comment: I appreciate this but I am morbidly lazy and don't feel like rewriting 2/3 of my code even though it would be easier to deal with the last 1/3, hah. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *absolutely* have no control over the input **format**, then consider the following text file:

```
---------------
0,
test1
test@gmail
19/12/2016
---------------
1,
test2
test2@gmail
01/01/2016
```

Then:

```
from datetime import datetime

present = datetime.now()  # Get current time
print("Present time: ", present.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')) # Format present time

with open("birthday.txt") as database:
    file_data = database.read()

# splitting by separator
info = [line.strip() for line in file_data.split('---------------') if line]
print(info)
# ['0,\ntest1\ntest@gmail\n19/12/2016', '1,\ntest2\ntest2@gmail\n01/01/2016']

for line in info:
    _, name_bday, mail_bday, date_bday = line.split('\n')
    list_date = datetime.strptime(date_bday, "%d/%m/%Y")
    print(list_date)
    # 2016-12-19 00:00:00 first iteration
    # 2016-01-01 00:00:00 second iteration
```

Comment: Thank you. :) I added `list_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')` because I need the format we use in Europe